# What does operator ~= mean in Lua?

Tags: lua, operators

What does the `~=` operator mean in Lua?

For example, in the following code:

```
if x ~= params then
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

the `~=` is `not equals`

It is the equivalent in other languages of `!=`

Comment: thanks a lot caulitomaz. yes, it makes a lot of sense - almost obvious in retrospective.

Comment: Makes no sense actually, since ~ is the mathematical symbol of approximately equal ... would maybe make sense if it was the same as an == in js tho :p

Comment: I suppose on second thought A != B mathematically means factorial of A is equal to B ... so maybe I can forgive Lua being written in C but not just using the C style != operator :p

Answer (score 15):

> The operator ~= is exactly the negation of equality (==).

See [docs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.3).

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing to the docs pushkin - for some reason googling ~= did not work for me. But now that I see the code, it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 7):

During compilation it gets translated to `not a == b`.

Answer (score 2):

`~=` in Lua, is just like doing `!=` in other languages like C#.